# How to convert XML to JSON using python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

How to convert XML to JSON using python script

XML is OAGIS® Revision: 9.2 format.

I am using this program for converting but i am not getting required output

```
import json
import xmltodict

with open("input.xml", 'r') as f:
    xmlString = f.read()

    # print("XML input (input.xml):")
    # print(xmlString)

    jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmlString), indent=4)

    print("\nJSON output(output.json):")
    print(jsonString)

    with open("output.json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(jsonString)
```

This is my XML format
[Download](https://controlc.com/1f7c79b9)

Required output format:-

Simple NDJSON key-value pairs like below

```
{
   "ID_XXXXXXXXXXXX_ID":0,
   "ID":"U",
   "INSRT_UPDT_DATE":"2012-05-02 10:42:50.1600000",
   "S_CD":"Open"
}
```

Comment: I realize that this is not directly answering your question, but would something like [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) suit your needs? You could try it using `pandoc -s input.xml -o output.json` to see if you get lucky...